# Axis tick marks re positioning in R

Tags: r

I am having an issue with where tick marks are landing on an axis for a heatmap I am putting together. Below is the code to generate what I am getting currently as well as an image of what I am trying to achieve. I know that it is possible in ggplot2 (see: [shifting tick positions in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10710463/how-to-force-the-x-axis-tick-marks-to-appear-at-the-end-of-bar-in-heatmap-graph)) but I would like to do it in basic R packages. Thank you.

```
colfunc <- colorRampPalette(c("white", gray(.3, alpha = NULL)))
colorBarz=matrix(seq(0,7,len=14),nrow=1)
colorBarx=1
colorBary=seq(0,7,len=14)
cus_breaks=c(seq(0,7,len=15))
image(colorBarx,colorBary,colorBarz,col=colfunc(14),axes=FALSE,xlab="",ylab="",breaks=cus_breaks,cex.lab=2)
box(which="plot")
axis(2,at=seq(from = 0, to = 7, by = 1),las=2,cex.axis=2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will this work?

```
colfunc <- colorRampPalette(c("white", gray(.3, alpha = NULL)))
colorBarz=matrix(seq(0,7,len=14),nrow=1)
colorBarx=1
colorBary=seq(0,7,len=15)
cus_breaks=c(seq(0,7,len=15)) 
image(colorBarx,colorBary,colorBarz,col=colfunc(14),axes=FALSE,xlab="",ylab="",breaks=cus_breaks,cex.lab=2,ylim=c(0,7))
box(which="plot")
axis(2,at=seq(from = 0, to = 7, by = 1),las=2,cex.axis=2)
```